# Angular2: How to change iFrame src?

Tags: javascript, angular, iframe

I am new to Angular2 and trying to change iframe's url on click of a button. Got passed couple of hurdles like `safe url` and `setting the src for iframe`. Can't figure out a nice way to change the url on click of buttons/links. 
How can change the iFrame url based on the button id?

**HTML**

```
<button md-button (click)="updateSrc($event)"  id="first" class="top-link">First</button>
  <button md-button  (click)="updateSrc($event)" id="second" class="top-link">Second</button>

<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" [src]="changeUrl()"></iframe>
```

**Component**

```
private first_url = "some url";
private second_url = "some other url":

updateSrs(event) {
    console.log('Here');
    console.log(event.currentTarget.id);
    this.reportUrl();
  }
;
  changeUrl() {
    return this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(this.first_url);
  }
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

no need to deal with the event for such a thing as you can access component properties from the template...

### template:

```
<button md-button (click)="updateSrc(first_url)"  id="first" class="top-link">First</button>
<button md-button  (click)="updateSrc(second_url)" id="second" class="top-link">Second</button>

<iframe id="frame" frameborder="0" [src]="current_url"></iframe>
```

### ts :

```
first_url = "some url";
second_url = "some other url":
current_url: SafeUrl;


updateSrc(url) {
    this.current_url=this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url)
  }
```

Comment: Do I still need to call `this.reportUrl()`? I am not using it anywhere on the template.

Comment: You put it in your code, I thought it was a side-effect, but it's not needed for this code, indeed...